# random order python

Tags: python, random

I have to make a quiz for a project. I have the question and 3 answers but the correct one always come on the top. How do I shuffle my answers?

```
QS = []
for row in data:
         row.append(2)
         QS.append(row)

while True:
    x=random.randint(0,len(QS)-1)
    if QS[x][2]>0:
        print QS[x][0]
        break


while True:
    if QS[x][2]>0:
        print QS[x][1]
        break

while True:
    xy=random.randint(0,len(QS)-1)
    if xy!=x:
        print QS[xy][1]
        break
while True:
    xyz=random.randint(0,len(QS)-1)
    if xyz!=xy and xyz!=xy:
        print QS[xyz][1]
        break
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [random.shuffle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle). First create a list of valid answer and use random.shuffle to create a random shuffle

An example demonstration

```
>>> import random
>>> ans = ['ans1', 'ans2', 'ans3']
>>> random.shuffle(ans)
>>> ans
['ans1', 'ans3', 'ans2']
```

Comment: could you try to do it with my code if possible if needed i could send you the information needed it would be really appreciated